# How to Check the Batch Promt action choice, in Batch processing?

Tags: dialog, batch-processing, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

In my customClass **extends** `RunBaseBatch` in method `main` I need to check the choice selected in to *Batch Promt* (if is *OK* or *Cancel*), in case the Flag **Batch processing** is selected ON.

[image: BatchDialog]

```
server public static void main(Args _args = null)
{
    MyCustomClass_BATCH localMyCustomClass_BATCH;

    localMyCustomClass_BATCH= new MyCustomClass_BATCH ();

    if (localMyCustomClass_BATCH.prompt() )
    {
        localMyCustomClass_BATCH.run();
    }   

    // HERE I want to check the action selected, if it's OK or Cancel.
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `prompt` returns true, OK was pressed and it is not in batch.
It returns false, if cancel is pressed or batch was selected.

The OK/Cancel does not belong to the Batch pane, but to the runbase dialog as such.

You can test whether batch was selected or not, but I do not see a great use case for this.

```
server public static void main(Args _args)
{
    MyCustomClass_BATCH myThing = new MyCustomClass_BATCH();    
    if (myThing.prompt())
        myThing.run(); // OK, not in batch
    else if (myThing.batchInfo().parmBatchExecute())
        info("We will go batch");
    else
        info("Action cancelled");
}
```

The `myThing.batchInfo().parmBatchExecute()` *will* return false if Cancel was pressed, even if "Batch processing" was checked in the dialog. Check the source of `RunBaseBatch.prompt` to see why.

Comment: Thanks @Jan B. Kjeldsen, nice Answer. Work well.